# Capturar los atributos de un select

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Lo que necesito es pasar el precio al `input` que esta almacenado en un atributo `data`, ya que viene la info de una base de datos.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<select asp-for="Venta.CodProducto" class="form-control" id="codpro">

    <option>Seleccione una opcion</option>
            @foreach (var producto in Model.Productos)
            {
                <option value="@producto.CodProducto" data-precio="@producto.Precio">
                    @producto.Nombres @producto.Descripcion
                </option>
            }
</select>

<label class="control-label">Precio</label>
<input class="form-control" type="number"id="ValorPro"/>



<script>

let opcion = $('#codpro option:selected');

$('#opcion').on('change', function () {
    let precio = $(opcion).attr('data-precio');
    $('#ValorPro').val(precio);
});


</script>
```

Comment: Hola Vanesa, como recomendación te diría que elijas una [convención para los nombres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_nombres_(programaci%C3%B3n)) y te apegues a esta. Esto te va a ahorrar dolores de cabeza por errores de tipeo.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el `precio` del `<option>` seleccionado tenes que:

- Suscribirte al evento `change` en el `<select>`
- Cuando se ejecuta el evento, buscar el `<option>` seleccionado y de éste obtener el precio establecido en el [atributo `data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

#### Ejemplo:

```js
// Suscribimos al evento "change" del <select>
$('#codpro').on('change', function() {

  // Obtenemos el <option> seleccionado
  let $option = $(this.selectedOptions[0]);

  // Pasamos el precio al <input>
  $('#ValorPro').val($option.data('precio'));
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @VanesaAcevedo, un gusto poder ayudarte. Si alguna de las respuestas que recibiste ayudo a resolver tu pregunta, considera votarla y/o marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Debes acceder a `#codpro`, que es el `<select>`. El evento será escuchado cuando ocurre el `change` en el `<select>`, es decir, cuando seleccionamos una opción:

```
$('#codpro').on('change', function () {
  // ...
}
```

Luego ingresamos a la opción que seleccionamos:

```
$('#codpro').on('change', function () {
  let opcion = $('#codpro option:selected');
}
```

Y de esa opción, al atributo `data-precio`:

```
$('#codpro').on('change', function () {
  let opcion = $('#codpro option:selected');
  let precio = $(opcion).attr('data-precio');
}
```

Y por último, asignas ese valor del atributo a `#ValorPro`, quedando el código así:

```
$('#codpro').on('change', function () {
  let opcion = $('#codpro option:selected');
  let precio = $(opcion).attr('data-precio');
  $('#ValorPro').val(precio);
});
```